# how can i close position on copy trade order via ccxt?

Tags: python, ccxt

```
 side = data['strategy']['order_action'].upper()
quantity = data['strategy']['order_contracts']
ticker = data['ticker']
curposition =data['strategy']['market_position']
if (curposition=='long'):
    order('buy',quantity,ticker)
elif(curposition=='short'):
    order('sell',quantity,ticker)
elif(curposition=='flat'):
    bitget.post_closeTrackOrder(symbol='ETHUSDT_UMCBL',trackingNo='currentTrack')
**strong text**
```

here is my python code and idk what to use in close copytrade positions..
PS:i`m using bitget now.

Comment: Can you get a bit more information? Are you getting an error message? Not exactly sure what your question is. Which library are you using?

Comment: You normally need to use the `createOrder` method to close a position with params equal to `{'reduce_only': true}`, but you need to share more code for people to understand what you're trying to do